# Errors while using the updated mediapipe version

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, compatibility, mediapipe

I updated mediapipe to the latest version. I am using python 3.9. The rest of the packages are also compatible. The first problem I encountered was with Protobuf, but I downgraded it to the required version. Then there was a new `no module found` error in the `buider.py` file.

By following a solution provided on this platform, I installed the latest version of Protobus and then copied the builder.py file. Afterwards, I downgraded protobuf to the required version and pasted the builder file in the required folder i.e. `...\Lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal`.

When I ran the program again, it gave a new error:

```py
File "D:\PyCharm\thesis\pyqt5\app\final\Head n FER final.py", line 7, in <module>
    import mediapipe as mp
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import mediapipe.python.solutions as solutions 
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    import mediapipe.python.solutions.drawing_styles
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\drawing_styles.py", line 20, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python.solutions.drawing_utils import DrawingSpec
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\drawing_utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    from mediapipe.framework.formats import detection_pb2
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\framework\formats\detection_pb2.py", line 14, in <module>
    from mediapipe.framework.formats import location_data_pb2 as mediapipe_dot_framework_dot_formats_dot_location__data__pb2
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\framework\formats\location_data_pb2.py", line 14, in <module>
    from mediapipe.framework.formats.annotation import rasterization_pb2 as mediapipe_dot_framework_dot_formats_dot_annotation_dot_rasterization__pb2
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\framework\formats\annotation\rasterization_pb2.py", line 19, in <module>
    _builder.BuildMessageAndEnumDescriptors(DESCRIPTOR, _globals)
  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\builder.py", line 64, in BuildMessageAndEnumDescriptors
    for (name, msg_des) in file_des.message_types_by_name.items():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'message_types_by_name'
```

What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: please show code that produced this. the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thank you for commenting. i resolved this error by changing the protobuf version. now solving other errors